# npm: Add a platform specific dependency

Tags: node.js, npm

In NPM documentation, there is an `os` [option for platform specific dependency](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#os).

My `package.json` contains `fsevents`, which is a must on MacOS for performance reasons. On the other hand, it causes error on Windows.

```
"dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.17.0",
        "electron": "^1.6.11",
        "electron-packager": "^8.7.2",
        "electron-reload": "^1.2.2",
        "electron-store": "^1.3.0",
        "flatpickr": "^4.0.7",
        "fsevents": "^1.1.2",
```

So how exactly do I use the `os` option?

Answer (score 0):

Its work around i tried

Add to your package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "install": "node install_dependencies.js"
}
```

And then add a **install_dependencies.js** file that checks the OS - which run npm install.

Answer (score 0):

fsevents should be an optional dependency which raises a warning but not an error during install. Which version of npm are you using? Try upgrading. There are at least a couple of buggy versions of npm will break this.

https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v3.10.10

```
REGRESSION FIX: 9aebe98 #14117 Fixes a bug where installing a shrinkwrapped
package would fail if the platform failed to install an optional dependency
included in the shrinkwrap.
```

https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v5.4.2

```
0b28ac72d #18458 Fix a bug on Windows where rolling back of failed optional
dependencies would fail.
```

Comment: I am using npm 5.4.2 on MacOS as the developing machine, and 5.4.2 on Windows 7 as the staging machine. Don't think the bug applies, because it is *rolling back*. I explicitly include `fsevents` on Mac because even though one of `webpack-dev-server`'s dependency list it as optional dependency, it does not get installed. Required or else high CPU utilization when running `webpack-dev-server`

Comment: sounds like the issue is more about why it isn't being installed by `webpack-dev-server`. If you remove it from your dependancies, do you still see a warning on windows install? (you should, and if you do then it's attempting the install, so something's up on the mac)

Comment: If I remove `fsevents` then no problem on Windows. The problem is `npm install` or `npm install --only-dev` does not install fsevents on Mac, because it is an optional dependency of another 3 layers of dependency below `webpack-dev-server`